# How to create a key(like FBAppid) automatically for registration?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I need to create an auto generated key and send through the mail for a registration process.The key should have atleast 50 characters(like facebook Appid) length and must be unique . I am using php technology and mysql as data base.

I am new to php and need help.

Comment: if you want to settle for 40 you can use `sha1`

Comment: Take a look at [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid), you could concatenate the email and user name with values returned from it and then trim it to 50 characters if necessary

Comment: What exactly do you expect the output to be ("combination of email, username etc...") and what problem do you have in generating this?

Comment: I think the key should be random, not based on user data. If it's based on user data, it can be calculated outside of your application and could be used maliciously.

Comment: What level of security is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for exactly 50 chars and cryptographically safe string use.

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(50);
```

Comment: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is definitivly more serious than other options. One problem though: if the server will generate keys at (not so) high rate, it will soon exhaust its entropy pool...

Comment: @Sylvain For that you really need to generate *a lot* of keys (seeing as the OP wants to use it in case of registrations... come on, he's not going to have Facebook level numbers of registrations...) and it's still going to give you better results than anything else.

Comment: @deceze "generate a lot of keys" Really? I don't have figures in mind -- but as far as I remember, the default entropy pool size of Linux is 4096 bits, and, depending the algorithm used, it consumes from 128 to 256 per key. Depending the load on the server, the entropy pool could re-fill up rapidly or not. But as I said in the beginning, "as far as I remember". Someone else might come with more definitive comment on this.

Comment: @Sylvain I don't have any numbers for this either, but it does indeed depend on how quickly the pool refills. I seriously doubt there are going to be so many registrations that the pool won't refill in-between.

Comment: @deceze you probably are in the right ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include username etc. in your confirmation code. All you need is a random string. Here's a function which will generate a cryptographically safe string for you.

```
function random_string($length = 50)
{
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2);
    return substr(str_replace(array('/', '+', '='), '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a hash from any string.

As long as the source string is unique, the hash will be too.

For example you can use the inscription timestamp with the user id (to avoid duplicate in case of 2 user register at the same second), then use any hash function (md5 for 32 chars, sha1 for 40, another for 50)

unqid is generated from the current time and is allmost unique (99.99% of the time, because collision can happend if uniqid is called at the same microsecond).

openssl_random_pseudo_bytes might generate random string, but the implementation isn't specified enough in the documentation to be sure about collision risks. And you need to convert it to a more standart string with bin2hex for safe use in urls.

Comment: The key problem while generating "random keys" in not to generate *by accident* two identical key. The real thread is that someone could *guess* the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this function

```
function genRandomString()    {        $length = 10;   
$characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";      
$string ="" ;             
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {       
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];      
}       

return $string;
```

}

any number of length u can use